# Will a servlet inherit the async-supported attribute of its superclass servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

This question is about the possibility of inheritance of the `async-supported` attribute of servlets (and filters) as defined in the project's **web.xml** file.

In my code, the `ScoresServlet` subclasses the `AppServlet` , e.g:

```
public class AppServlet extends HttpServlet{}

public class ScoresServlet extends AppServlet{}
```

In the project's web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AppServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>a.b.AppServlet</servlet-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ScoresServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>c.d.ScoresServlet</servlet-class> 
    </servlet>
```

I am curious.

Will subclasses of an async-support enabled servlet inherit its async-supported state?